# Python regex to match word before <

Tags: python, regex

So I want to match something like this -

```
foo <TEST>something something </TEST> blah
```

I want a regex that gets me the foo, but does not get me the something. I was thinking of using a regex that was something like this

```
(\w\s)<
```

with a negative lookahead, but I'm not sure how to use that in this case.

OTHER CASES-

```
something something foo <TEST> something something </TEST> blah
```

Comment: Could you give more examples? NOTE: If that's HTML or XML, regex is not suitable.

Comment: the first something isn't before a `<` - do you want to match that one too?

Comment: @Claudiu read again: he DOESN'T want to match `something`, only `foo`

Comment: yeah - I'll add more examples and no, I'm not matching HTML

Comment: @praks5432 And the expected output as well.

Comment: @adsmith: yes but he said match word before `<` in the title, it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Claudiu I find his title to be a great summary of his question.

Comment: @adsmith: ok but if it is taken literally as-is then the first line would match both `foo` and `something`, since both of them occur before a `<`, no?

Comment: @Claudiu only to those respondents who didn't take the time to read the question, of course....

Comment: @adsmith: well I read the question and it still wasn't clear for me. maybe i am the only one. anyways it's understood now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
\w+(?=\s*<[^/])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tR7jV0)

The positive lookahead `(?=\s*<[^/])` ensures that there are optional spaces followed by a `<` which is not followed by a `/` ahead.

```
\w+     matches one or more \w
(?=     beginning of positive lookahead
  \s*   optional spaces
  <     a < character
  [^/]  not a / character
)       end of positive lookahead
```

Answer (score 2):

Negetive look-ahead will do just fine.

```
(\S+)\s*<(?!/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own version

```
^(?P<Word>\S*\W)*<
```

See it in action  http://regex101.com/r/tS6hM2